# How to create a System.Drawing.Color from its hexadecimal RGB string?

Tags: .net, colors, parsing, hex, system.drawing.color

I want to create a `System.Drawing.Color` from a value like `#FF00FF` or `FF00FF` without needing to write code for that. There is any .NET built-in parser for that?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF00FF");
```

Answer (score 65):

You can use the System.Drawing.ColorTranslator static method FromHtml.

use:

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
```

Answer (score 19):

It is rather easy when you use the [Convert-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx). The [`ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) function has an overload with a second parameter which represents the base the string is in.

```
using System.Drawing

Color yourColor = Color.FromARGB(Convert.ToInt32("FF00FF", 16));
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colorconverter.aspx) class:

```
var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof( Color ) );
color = converter.ConvertFromString( "#FF00FF" );
```

This can also convert from the standard named colors e.g. ConvertFromString( "Blue" )

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy580hbd.aspx) for a discussion of the standard .NET type conversion mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

If the color you want to use is a constant, in C# use `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb (0xFF00FF)`. That is slightly faster than `System.Drawing.Color.FromName` or `System.Drawing.Color.FromHtml`, since the parsing from a string to integer is done at compile time rather than at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

The FromName method worked for me

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#FF00FF");
```